# How to emulate intents through espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have developed an App which starts through an intent-filter and get data from  this intent.

The data will be decrypted and used to fill up my UI. Could I simulate this intent using espresso? how?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Related: [Android Espresso receive Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34625825/1608670)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES, mArrayList);
    setActivityIntent(i);

    // Espresso will not launch 
    //our activity for us, we must launch it via getActivity().
    getActivity();
```