# Android Espresso Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-espresso

My test file looks like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class CreateNewSessionActivityTest {
    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<CreateNewSessionActivity> mActivityRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(CreateNewSessionActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is my auth token");

        final Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

        intending(hasComponent(hasShortClassName(".CreateNewSessionActivity"))).respondWith(result);

        onView(withId(R.id.create_new_session_auth_token_edit_text)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.create_new_session_auth_token_edit_text)).check(matches(withText("this is my auth token")));
    }
}
```

In the `CreateNewSessionActivity.onCreate` method I execute the following:

```
final Intent intent = this.getIntent();

if (intent != null) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    final String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            final String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

            if (sharedText != null) {
                authTokenEditText.setText(sharedText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also registered the Intent Filter in the Manifest underneath the activity.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The code in the activity also does work. If I use any app and share text to it it'll be displayed in the EditText.

However this line fails in the test:

```
onView(withId(R.id.create_new_session_auth_token_edit_text)).check(matches(withText("this is my auth token")));
```

The text won't be displayed in the EditText at all. Is there anything wrong with the way I want to test the Intent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`intending` is for testing outgoing intents. To test incoming intent, use an `ActivityRule` with the third argument as `false`.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
    CreateNewSessionActivity.class,
    true,    // initialTouchMode
    false);  // launchActivity. False to set intent.
```

Then launch your activity this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is my auth token");
activityRule.launchActivity(intent);
```

See http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/espresso-21-activitytestrule.html for more info.

Comment: thanks a lot! One question which is not really related. I do show a dialog in the application upon start if some criteria is met. That dialog is failing the test. Since the dialog is over the view that I want to test. How can I specify what the parent / root of `create_new_session_auth_token_edit_text` is?

Comment: Please post a different question

Comment: if somebody have error with `@Rule`, change it to `@get:Rule`. Most of the time, it can solve the error.